# jackson-dataformat-xml breaks defualt config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a RestController which receives a XML POST Request.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/check", consumes = { MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }, produces = MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CheckResponse> checkRequest(
            @RequestBody(required = true) CheckRequest checkRequest) {
    //Code...
}
```

The body looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:CheckRequest>
  <UserIp>1.1.1.1</UserIp>
  <AgencyManagement>
    <Customer>123456</Customer>
    <Office>abcde</Office>
  </AgencyManagement>
</ns2:CheckRequest>
```

I'm using the default converter configuration and the `CheckRequest` Object is filled with data.

Now I like to save the request to the Database using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`. Using the default config its writing `JSON` instead of `XML`. So I added the following dependency to get the `XmlMapper.class` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**So if I start my application again and send the same request all the properties are empty when it arrives to the Controller.**

Why is this the case and how can I solve it?

Comment: Hi Patrick, did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: @CliffPereira, sorry no solution found until now. Used Jaxb to generate xml manually